# USB to HDMI adapters or simmilar

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, lenovo, hdmi

In recent times I have been needing to plug a third monitor into my laptop (Lenovo ideapad gaming 3) for some more mediocre tasks (I do not need a high speed connection to it). My main HDMI port is already utilized and the USB-C port is data only as specified in the data sheet, aswell as with testing, where with a thinkpad external hub, which I plug into via the USB-C port, plugged in monitors aren't found.

So my question is, I have been looking into usb to hdmi/vga adapters, but most I find are not supported for linux, so does anyone know any that are supported with Ubuntu 20.04, or is there possibly a better way which I am not aware of on how to connect this monitor to my pc.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Maybe a docking station dedicated for your laptop will work?

Comment: @raj I originally thought so too - so I searched on lenovos website, however came up empty, I guess there are no docks for this laptop.